# Recover a SSIS project from a SSIS package

Tags: ssis, project, package

I was developing a SSIS project, but accidentaly, I erased it. However I keep a copy of the SSIS package. So my question is, it is posible recover the project using the package? or is someway to read the package content to start over the project?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't remember there being anything too essential stored in the project files for SSIS projects - you can create a new project and then 'Add Existing Item...' and add the package(s).

Answer (score 0):

@Will gave you the correct solution.  Project files are XML files that list which packages are part of a project.  You can add an existing package back without any issues.  You can even manually add a node if you want by editing the file directly.  I use to find this useful before BIDS Helper offered sorting capabilities.

You may also want to implement a version control system if you are working with SSIS.  Every once in a blue moon a package gets into a funky, unrecoverable state and we have to rollback to a previous version to get it working again.  This happens about 4 times a year for a team of 6 people who work on 100-200 packages.  Also, you will never lose a package again even if you erase it on the server and your local copy is wiped out.